# WSHttpBinding: Entropy.BinarySecret role in message encryption

Tags: python, soap, wshttpbinding, wsse

I am writing a simple SOAP client application in Python.

WSDL file can be found here: https://clients.nationalmailing.com.au/ServiceTest/OrderService.svc?wsdl

Unfortunately the server declared usage of `wsHttpBinding` in its WSDL file and I had to learn how many troubles it brings to not-.NET developers.

I have working C# code (and it is pretty simple there) and used Fiddler to capture the traffic and analyze messages. Now I know the structure to follow. Client sends 2 subsequental messages.

I managed to create and send first request and receive a response from the server. BUT second request is a way more complex. I have found a library [signxml](https://signxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which helped me to create `<Signature>` structure with all the fields that should present (as per captured traffic).

But the server continues to answer with "Error 500: An error occurred when verifying security for the message."

I realized that in the first message I put just random values for the following structure:

```
<s:Body>
        <trust:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
            <trust:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512/sct</trust:TokenType>
            <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
            <trust:Entropy>
                <trust:BinarySecret
                 u:Id="uuid-0649fd7a-9ae2-4f9f-964c-e3aa5d68e8cd-1" 
                 Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Nonce">h/MaeQVSL5Br30Hnt/SAl274flYfZVZyx2Fri9zNuEY=</trust:BinarySecret>
            </trust:Entropy>
            <trust:KeySize>256</trust:KeySize>
        </trust:RequestSecurityToken>
    </s:Body>
```

**The value of `BinarySecret` is just a random string encoded with Base64**. I think this should be an issue on this stage. I also do not use the same parameters from server's response.

Could anyone explain how should I use `Entropy.BinarySecret` - should it take part in the calculations of `Signature` and how it is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. Yes, the issue was in improper usage of `Entropy` parameter.

To sign the message you need to generate a key, it consists of two parts (client entropy and server's entropy). They get combined with `P_SHA1` algorithm into a key.

To anyone who find this post in the future: for Python have a look on `signxml` library and section 4 of [ws-trust spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/v1.4/ws-trust.pdf).